# WinForms create application walkthrough

Tags: c#, winforms, walkthrough

I would like to create a application walkthrough for users to reveal functionality and give a short introduction to the software like this: http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/design/ux-flows-how-when-to-design-app-walkthrough
This is often used for smartphone apps or browser applications. I've never seen this for Windows applications before, but this should be possible or not?

The application is implemented in C# and WinForms and uses a lot of controls from Infragistics.

It isn't possible to find anything about that on google or SO because "walkthrough" could be anything... :/ Maybe I'm looking for the wrong keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible in a Windows App.  We've done something like this before.  I see your frustration regarding lack of documentation on the web.  There isn't a lot out there specifically for windows desktop.  Take what you can learn from the tutorial that you linked and translate that over.  What we did a lot of was used semi-transparent panels containing the necessary content and then just lay those over everything.  This way, you can get the 'greyed out' look for the main content of the app but control user's access.

Good luck!